# Azure Web App on Linux I change Scale Up and down then i reveice Application Error on website

Tags: azure-web-app-service

Website error message is:

:( Application Error
If you are the application administrator, you can access the diagnostic resources.

What i did

Restart Web App ( Still same error)
Restart Mysql  ( Still same error)
I search lots of pages can't find it right solutions

Answer (score 0):

App Service on Linux is only supported with Free, Basic, Standard, and Premium app service plans and does not have a Shared tier. You cannot create a Linux Web App in an App Service plan already hosting non-Linux Web Apps.
Also note that Based on the current limitation, for the same resource group you cannot mix Windows and Linux apps in the same region. 
If your application fails to start or you want to check the logging from your app, check the Docker logs in the LogFiles directory. You can access this directory either through your SCM site or via FTP. You may refer to this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/app-service-linux-intro  It would be more helpful if you can provide details like complete error message.

Comment: I dont understand what you saying to be honest, everything working very well on wordpress notting wrong then system web app down its self notting wrong with this. I will contact azure customer service we see what we can do it...